# Torch: Update tensor with non-zero elements

Tags: pytorch, torch

suppose I have:

```
>>> a = torch.tensor([1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 1])
>>> b = torch.tensor([0, 1, 3, 3, 0, 0])
```

I want to update b with elements in a if it's not zero. How can I beneficently do that?

Expected:

```
>>> b = torch.tensor([1, 2, 3, 3, 0, 1])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add to the previous answer and for more simplicity you can do it by one line of code:

```
b = torch.where(a!=0,a, b)
```

Output:

```
tensor([1, 2, 3, 3, 0, 1])
```

Answer (score 1):

`torch.where` is your answer. I assume based on your example that you also want to replace only elements in `a` that are 0.

```
mask = torch.logical_and(b!=0,a==0)
output = torch.where(mask,b,a)
```